# python variable expansion in multiple quotes using appium find elements

Tags: android, appium, python-appium

variable expansion is not happening inside multiple quotes. Here is the code

```
products = ['One','Two','Three'] 
for i in range(0,len(products)):
     el = self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().text("{}")').format(products[i])
                print (el)
```

expected result should be:

```
el = self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().text("One")')
```

Error Message:

```
File "temp_test.py", line 84, in test_product
    el = self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().text("{}")').format(products[i])
NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

Please help me to resolve this issue!!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got the answer with multiple tries(almost half a day). Its simple, the `.format(products[i])`  should specified inside the brackets() and end of the quotes.

```
products = ['One','Two','Three'] 
for i in range(0,len(products)):
     el = self.driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiSelector().text("{}")'.format(products[i]))
                print (el)
```